# How does Prolog optimize multiple calls to the same fact with same arguments

Tags: prolog

For example if I have this:

```
expensive(X, Y) :- % ... .

cheap(X, Y) :- expensive(X, Y), % ...
cheap2(X, Y) :- expensive(X, Y), % ...
```

and I call this:

```
perft(X, Y) :- expensive(X, Y), cheap(X, Y) , \+ cheap2(X, Y).
```

This is just hypothetical example, the question is does Prolog optimize the multiple calls to expensive fact, or do I have to find a better way to write this query so it doesn't call expensive fact twice, maybe cache the result somehow?

Comment: Prolog doesn't auto-optimize. The programmer has to write decent code. There are features such as https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog doesn’t optimize that away. I suspect because predicates can have side effects. It might read/write a file or print something to the terminal and so on. So Prolog can’t be sure that you don't get something different if you eliminate those duplicate calls.

That said, you can use [tabling](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling) to memoize individual predicates:

```
:- table expensive/2.

expensive(X, Y) :- ...
```

Comment: I just tried this, but that had no effect on performance, how do I make sure it is actually caching anything.

Comment: Can test using e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sleep/1 to add noticeable delays in the "slow" path.